# Alert Signal to Bybit from tradingview

Tags: webhooks, trading, tradingview-api, alerts

Sorry for my lack of Knowledge

But I need a signal from tradingview to bybit that will be going through a webhook, that longs when the alert longs and shorts when a alert shorts But it closes the previous trade when entering a new one. It also needs to be trading at a 12x Leverage.

Thanks For any Help that anyone can provide, Like an answer or a place i can get the answer.

I tried the Bybit code that it provided but it doesnt do the job. also tried some of the suggestions tradingview had, also tried youtube aswell

Comment: You should show us a clear example of what you are trying to do. Also, please show us what you already tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.